# Why is Richard golden?

Tags: support, design

On mobile view Richard appears with gold text. At first I blamed caching, and it was a mod thing. But even Rand Al'Thor's name isn't gold in the picture before:

[image: Richards name in golden text]

Comment: Maybe because you've visited Richard's profile page before, but not mine? (Also, you need to recharge your mobile.)

Comment: On my (computer) screen, everyone shows up as golden.

Comment: Silence is golden, and so am I.

Comment: @Richard If you go silent, what color do you turn?

Comment: Gold lantern....

Comment: @Richard:   Do you reject the standard nickname for Richard?   This question looks like a reference [to this](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0295178/). ....   [*How is babby formed?*](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Bnhdw3VkQ9Q/hqdefault.jpg)  *Why is Richard golden?*

Answer (score 7):

Because you've visited his profile page.

The [CSS](http://cdn.sstatic.net/skins/mobilemeta/all.css) make the unvisited link "strong blue".

```
.comment-user {
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #4A6FB1
}
```

The exact colour code for *visited* links is `#c18215`, which is described as "strong orange".

```
a:visited,
a:visited>em,
a:active,
a:active>em,
a:hover,
a:hover>em {
    color: #C18215
}
```

Comment: I am stupid then.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage Or the design that styles visited links tremendously different from unvisited links is.

Answer (score 4):

Because you've visited his profile page. See this screenshot that I just took: [image]

Richard is blue there.

After visiting his profile:
[image]

Look! It's gold!

(Just for fun, I took the shot on the same question that you did. :P)